# E-Mail ID format validation in a TextField using QML in Blackberry 10

Tags: regex, blackberry-10, email-validation

I have designed a login page in QML for my app on BB10.

In the username field I want to perform the email-id format validation.

How can I accomplish this ?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

To enter email and password we add two `TextField` in the `CommonDialog`.
You can try with this code

```
TextField {
    id: textFieldEmail
    width: contentColumn.width - textEmail.font.pixelSize*5
    echoMode: TextInput.Normal
    errorHighlight:false;
    placeholderText: qsTr( "Enter email" )
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.leftMargin:textEmail.font.pixelSize*5
    validator: RegExpValidator { regExp:/\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/ }
    onTextChanged: {
        textError.state ="hide";
        textError.text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use the `validator` there is an error that says `Unknown property`

Comment: The validator is available only since the last version of Cascades you have to download the latest SDK

Comment: I am currently using 10.0.9 sdk for windows